# impl PartialEq for an Enum so that multiple variants are equal

Tags: rust

I would like to define an enum where two different values are equal, however I want to do it without having to explicitly write out all the match cases for Test::B == Test::B, Test::C == Test::C.

```
pub enum Test {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    AlsoA,
}
```

Maybe something like this, but without having to write out the comment marked part

```
impl PartialEq for Test {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Test) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (&Test::A, &Test::AlsoA) | (&Test::AlsoA, &Test::A) => true,

            // But without this part -------------------
            (&Test::A, &Test::A) => true,
            (&Test::B, &Test::B) => true,
            (&Test::C, &Test::C) => true,
            (&Test::AlsoA, &Test::AlsoA) => true,
            // -----------------------------------------

            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only ask one thing per question. It helps to keep questions at SO structured. For example, you second question (access the int values) has already been asked, but we can't close this SO-question as duplicate because it contains multiple questions. So it would be great to remove this second question of yours.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `#[repr(T)]` to the enum (where `T` is an integer type), and then compare their `as T` values:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Test {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    AlsoA,
}

impl PartialEq for Test {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Test) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (&Test::A, &Test::AlsoA) |
            (&Test::AlsoA, &Test::A) => true,
            (x, y) => *x as u8 == *y as u8,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use Test::*;
    assert!(A == A);
    assert!(B == B);
    assert!(C == C);
    assert!(AlsoA == AlsoA);
    assert!(A == AlsoA);
    assert!(AlsoA == A);
}
```

This also answers your second question: just add a `#[repr(T)]` and then use `as T`.